# FSPL formula for near magnetic field?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, magnetics, electromagnetic, field-strength

I would like to know the precise formula for the Free Space Path Loss in case of a Magnetic Field in the Near Field region.

We all know the popular FSPL formula, but this is only for the far field, where we have planewaves.

[image]
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-space_path_loss

---

I am looking for a near-field magnetic field path loss formula. How much strength does a magnetic field lose per distance from the source?

Is there any way to model this system. I could not find a formula on the entire internet, I was hoping somebody here would know.

Comment: In the near field we have to solve maxwell's equations to get anything sensible.

Comment: I recall the book Corsin and Lorrain have a page where they show the entire field ---- partA with range^2 atten and other partB with range^1 attenuation. Close in, the partA dominates. I'll hunt up the book, and look for that page.

Comment: Check out the following link.
http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/802/15/pub/04/15-04-0417-02-004a-near-field-channel-model.pdf

Comment: @MNSP Looks like the magnetic field strenght decays faster than the electric, which was my intuition as well. I will study it, thanks.